# Save a file as a hash map java

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I am very new to Java and I am working on a project. I have been told that in order to complete this project I will need to save a file into a hash map. This file contains words and their abbreviation so later on I want to be able to search for a particular word and then return the abbreviation for it. I have been able to make the hash map and access the file, but I'm stuck on how to save it into the hash map.

```
public Shortener() {
    Map<String, String> abbrevFile = new HashMap<String, String>();
    File file = new File("C:\\abbreviations.txt");
```

Comment: Well, what format do you want the file to have? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ... what Jon said and: You need to read the file row by row, I guess. Then split each row and add the parts as key and value to the map. You should be able to look up these steps individually.

Comment: My file is currently set out like this:
word, abbreviation 
word, abbreviation 
word, abbreviation 

I'm not quite sure how to read a file line by line as I am really new to Java. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I would use a properties file as it's an existing format.

e.g.

```
Hello=Hi
Abreviation=Abr
```

such as

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(file);
abbrevFile.putAll((Map) p);
```

To look up the map you can do

```
public String lookup(String word) {
    return abbrevFile.get(word);
}
```

Comment: How would this work for when I want to then just return the abbreviation? I've never heard of properties before. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @Brigzy97 I have added how to lookup a map.

Comment: And this would just return only the abbreviation?

Comment: Okay thank you! I will definitely try this out

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of reading a file and storing the data in the hashmap

```
    static HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile(new File("words.txt"));
    }

    private static void readFile(File file) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               String[] args = line.split("-");
               wordList.put(args[0], args[1]);
            }

            System.out.println("Populated list with "+ wordList.size() + " words.");

            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Providing your format is in the following format

```
word-abbreviation
word-abbreviation
word-abbreviation
```

Comment: I can follow the majority of this but what does catch do? Thank you for your help. I can see how this works

Also I have never heard of bufferReader, is this just to read through the file?

Comment: I wouldn't catch and print the error here as this would be like pretending it doesn't matter the error occurred. Better to pass it to the caller.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Please can you explain this to me? Sorry for all the questions and my lack on knowledge

Comment: @Brigzy97 If you catch the exception here, the calling code will have no idea this happened and it will use the Map even though it might be empty whereas if you `throws` the Exception the caller can take a different action if an error occurs.

Comment: There should be no error here, providing the file is correctly closed and actually exists, so it should be nothing to worry about but yes, throwing the exception may be better.